# Where can I create a HashMap in the cloud that can be updated in realtime?

Tags: android, hashmap

Let's say in my Android application, I have a `HashMap` like this:

```
val VALUES: HashMap<String, Double> = hashMapOf(
    "value1" to 1,
    "value2" to 2,
)
```

Is there a way I can put this `HashMap` or a similar data structure in the cloud? I want to continually update it and add more values based on user activity from different users. The new values that are added to the `HashMap` come from different interactions from the users. I also want to access the data in `O(1)` time, which is why I'm using a HashMap in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Firebase Realtime DB, this will exactly fulfil your requirement.
even you can design your own structure and store data as per your requirement, this is a cloud-hosted NoSQL database.

https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start